# Effective printing from rest API output in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, rest

I'm running some simple GET requests against some software to extract and summarise data. I have been able to extract values from my rest API output and created a basic for loop to summarise the output. However I need to print it better so it is clearer for the end user. Hopefully the below description and examples will be able to show you what I'm trying to achieve.

```
user_response = user.json()
print(json.dumps(user_response, indent=2))
```

Rest output

```
user_response = {
  "total": 14,
  "offset": 0,
  "limit": 25,
  "list": [
    {
      "id": 1321,
      "url": "/v1/domains/1001/usersets",
      "name": "test1",
      "description": "test rest 1",
      "users": [
        {
          "uId": 1033,
          "uName": "harry",
          "gId": 1034,
          "gName": "harry"
        },
        {
          "uId": 1000,
          "uName": "luke",
          "gId": 1000,
          "gName": "luke"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 1257,
      "url": "/v1/domains/1001/usersets",
      "name": "test2",
      "description": "test rest 2",
      "users": [
        {
          "uName": "max"
        },
        {
          "uName": "joe"
        },
        {
          "uName": "polly"
        },
        {
          "uName": "tara"
        }
      ]
    },
```

I was eventually able to extract the name, description and the user data but the output isn't the easiest to read for the average end user using the code below

```
user_response = user_response['list']
    for x in user_response:
        print("Name: ", x['name'],"\n", "Description: ", x['description'])
        x = x['users']
        print("Users: ", "\n", x, "\n")
```

Output in the terminal

```
Name:  test1 
 Description:  test rest 1
Users:  
 [{'uId': 1033, 'uName': 'harry', 'gId': 1034, 'gName': 'harry'}, {'uId': 1000, 'uName': 'luke', 'gId': 1000, 'gName': 'luke'}] 

Name:  test2
 Description:  test rest 1
Users:  
 [{'uName': 'max'}, {'uName': 'joe'}, {'uName': 'polly'}, {'uName': 'tara'}]
```

I was hoping to print a new line for every dictionary within the list for better reading however I cannot find anything on how to do that and my code edits have been inconclusive.

```
Name:  test1 
Description:  test rest 1
Users:  
{'uId': 1033, 'uName': 'harry', 'gId': 1034, 'gName': 'harry'}, 
{'uId': 1000, 'uName': 'luke', 'gId': 1000, 'gName': 'luke'}

Name:  test2
Description:  test rest 2
Users:  
{'uName': 'max'}, 
{'uName': 'joe'},
{'uName': 'polly'},
{'uName': 'tara'}
```

Any ideas on how this can be achieved within my current for loop?

Also any tips on printing this data better would be much appreciated

Comment: You can try the [pprint module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/pprint.html). It will still print the square brackets, but otherwise gives your wanted output.

Comment: Printing the data in tabular format might be better to read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/printing-lists-as-tabular-data

Comment: I was not aware of either, thank you - something to explore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this example to format and print the output:

```
for i in user_response['list']:
    print('Name: {}'.format(i['name']))
    print('Description: {}'.format(i['description']))
    print('Users:')
    print(',\n'.join(str(u) for u in i['users']))
    print()
```

Prints:

```
Name: test1
Description: test rest 1
Users:
{'uId': 1033, 'uName': 'harry', 'gId': 1034, 'gName': 'harry'},
{'uId': 1000, 'uName': 'luke', 'gId': 1000, 'gName': 'luke'}

Name: test2
Description: test rest 2
Users:
{'uName': 'max'},
{'uName': 'joe'},
{'uName': 'polly'},
{'uName': 'tara'}
```